# Orphaned Class Module and 'Not enough memory' issue

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

A database that I have been working on appears to have run aground unfortunately I cant seem to get it back on track and it appears to be corrupted some what.

I removed 2 forms, but it appears that there class modules are still there when you access the vba console. When you then click on these modules you get the error message file not found.

I cant find any way to remove these modules.

At the same time as this issue arose I started having a problem with a form; when I try to open it in either design or form mode it wont open and I get an error message saying that it cant be opened and that I should try closing other applications.
Tried closing other applications but this has not resolved the issue.

I tried creating a new database and importing all of the desired forms, modules etc (excluding the aforementioned class modules) but I cant import the above form. An error message keeps appearing as stated earlier.

Does anyone have any ideas on a fix for this, and a way to avoid this issue in the future?

All advice greatly appreciated.

Noel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two main sources for dealing with corruption are:

http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/corruptmdbs.htm 
http://allenbrowne.com/ser-47.html

In this case, I would pay particular attention to /Decompile.

Comment: Remou thanks for those links they seem to have a lot of relevant and helpful info.

Comment: Decompile didn't manage to solve the issue unfortunately. Created a new database and imported the existing files (except the corrupted ones). Couldn't find a way to reopen the troublesome form and had to revert to an older back up version of it, which is a pain. This will act as a reminder to back up my work more frequently. Plenty of useful stuff on the links though Remou which will be a help now and in the future. Cheers.

Comment: @glinch It is a pity it did not get you out of the corner. I find fairly regular decompiles when you are developing helps to keep problems at bay. Also, make sure you do the development on a split mdb.

Comment: It's not just backups -- you ne3ed to follow better coding practices, which means turn off COMPILE ON DEMAND, always use OPTION EXPLICIT in all modules, compile regularly (every few lines of code) and decompile after any significant coding. This will keep your VBA code clean and free of crud, which makes it susceptible to corruption.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton cheers for all the advice. I try to compile reguarly and split the databse, but had never came accross decompiling before. @David-W-Fenton taken on board your advice for better coding practice and will incorporate this into my coding routine.